# how does the xml looks like according the complex type object defined in wsdl

Tags: android, xml, web-services, ksoap2

**Wsdl** defined the complex type like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="RequestParam">
  <xs:all>
  <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="CertifyRequest" type="flwsxs:CertifyRequestData" /> 
  <xs:complexType name="CertifyRequestData">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="apId" type="xs:string" /> 
    <xs:element name="apPassword" type="xs:string" /> 
    <xs:element name="tenantId" type="xs:string" /> 
    <xs:element name="params" type="flwsxs:RequestParam" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
```

The parameter params use the complex type RequestParam, but if I want to send the xml to webservice, does it look like follow?

```
 <sch:CertifyRequest>
         <sch:apId>hunkd</sch:apId>
         <sch:apPassword>hunkd</sch:apPassword>
         <sch:tenantId>hunkd</sch:tenantId>
         <sch:params>
            <sch:RequestParam>
            <sch:key>txtId</sch:key>
            <sch:value>test</sch:value>
        </sch:RequestParam>
        <sch:RequestParam>
            <sch:key>txtPassword</sch:key>
            <sch:value>123</sch:value>
        </sch:RequestParam>
         </sch:params>
      </sch:CertifyRequest>
```

Above **xml** is generated by **soap-ui** except the parameters params. Can anyone tell me this is wrong or right? Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Any advice will be appreciate!!!

Comment: it seems accurate, did you try sending that as it is form soapUI ?

Comment: yes,i use soap-ui send and edit the xml's parameter generated by wsdl.but server response fall, response is right xml,but response parameter was not what i expected. So i suspect the params parameter was not correct formed(which was not generated by soap ui from wsdl).

Comment: what does the server return as an error msg?

Comment: Thanks for your guys concerning.I solved this problem. the 'params' parameter formed wrong.if i want to add two params object.this is right xml: <params><key></key><value></value></params><params><key></key><value></value></params>